# Game of Life pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am creating game of Life in C and I am getting this segmentation fault (core dumped) error after the program takes input from user. I recently started learning C and my understanding of pointers is basic .I have not been able to find a fix for it after looking online and trying different ways to get it right. If i dont use pointers and keep it simple everything works right.I would appreciate any help

```
   int main() {

    int maxR;               
    int maxC;               
    int generations;        
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int n;                  //neighbour count
    char state;
    char **board;         //original boardfor comparison
    char **newBoard;        //boardto make changes to

    scanf("%d %d %d",&maxR,&maxC,&generations);             //take input

    board= (char**)malloc(maxR * sizeof(char*));         //allocating memory
    newBoard=(char**) malloc(maxR * sizeof(char*));        //allocating memory

    for(i=0; i<maxR; i++) {
        board[i] = malloc(maxC * sizeof (char));          //allocating memory
        newBoard[i] = malloc(maxC * sizeof (char));         //allocating memory
        for(j=0; j<maxC; j++) {
            scanf (" %c", &board[i][j]);                  //getting input
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<=generations; i++ ) {                        
        for (j=0; j<maxR; j++) {                            
            for (k=0; k<maxC; k++) {                        
                state=board[j][k];                        
                n=countNeighbours(board,maxR,maxC,j,k);   

                if(state == '1') {                          //if the cell is alive
                    if(n==2 || n==3) newBoard[j][k] = '1';  //if the cell has 2 or 3 neighbours then it lives
                    else newBoard[j][k]='0';                //else the cell dies

                } else {                                     //else (if) the cell is dead
                    if(n==3) newBoard[j][k]='1';            //but has 3 neibours then the cell become alive
                    else newBoard[i][j]='0';                //else it dies
                }
            }
        }
        memcpy(board, newBoard,sizeof(board));          //copy the updated grid to the old one
    }

    printBoard(board,maxR,maxC);                          

    deallocate(board,maxR);                               //deallocatethe memory
    deallocate(copyGrid,maxR);                              //deallocatethe memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one obvious problem here.

```
memcpy(oldGrid, copyGrid,sizeof(oldGrid));          //copy the updated grid to the old one
```

As `oldGrid` is a `char**` pointer, then `sizeof(oldGrid)` is the size of a pointer, which is probably 4 or 8 bytes depending on your platform. So, you're not copying the grid, you're only copying a few bytes of it.

If you want to copy the whole grid, you need to work out the size of the grid in bytes.

If `oldGrid` was declared as an array, instead of a pointer, then `sizeof(oldGrid)` would yield the full size of the grid as you expect. Arrays behave differently from pointers when it comes to `sizeof()`.

Comment: Yes, briefly- you need to put there size of instance, not size of the pointer, that's what are you doing now. Its nice you have sizeof there, you you will get inside the size of pointers, not the size of the grid.

Comment: thanks for the response. If i use two for loops to copy one grid to another instead of memcpy the program still crashes after user input

Comment: @James, maybe in the 2nd for loop in main() function. 'else copyGrid[i][j]='.';' would be the problem. Your intention was 'else copyGrid[j][k]='.';' ? huh?

Comment: @Kay yes you are right that fixes the problem.Thanks alot.